# Passport Laravel Rest API Auth With Normal Design

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, passport.js, laravel-blade, laravel-passport

I have Completely assigned the Passport REST API and i get token and tested on PostMan  [image]

and it retrieve the data with this Auth

this is normal js html with laravel blade view (NOT VUE.JS)

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "**********/api/User/GetPost",
  headers: {
      'Authorization':'Bearer Tokenblablabla',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
  },
  data: null,
  success: function(data){
  console.log('succes: '+data);
  }
```

});

this is the controller function

```
    public function GetPosts(Request $request){
         $data3="Test"
         return response()->json([
            'Success'=> true,
            'Message'=>'8',
            'Data' => $data3,
         ], 200);
    }
```

this is api.php // this will return a json with posts details

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:api'],function(){
      Route::post('/GetPosts','Wall\PostsController@GetPosts');
});
```

this is web.php

```
Route::get('/GetPost', function () {
     return view('getpostview');
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

i get confused i cannot send Auth beside i cannt retrieve the json from API iam 3 days STUCK in this problem 
what iam need to connect the normal laravel blade to another laravel passport REST API

Answer (score 0):

The Blade templates generated by Laravel for authentication can works with Laravel Passport, JWT, etc.

The thing that you need to do is configure [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#installation) properly.

Do not forget to modify the driver specified in the API `config/auth.php` file:

```php
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Also, to retrieve a json response **add this header** in your requests:

> 'Accept' : 'application/json'

So your request should be like this:

```php
$response = $client->request('GET', 'some-url/api/getPosts', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

---

## Side note

I encourage you to read [this presentation, "Teaching a Dog to REST"](https://es.slideshare.net/landlessness/teach-a-dog-to-rest), to create a clean, intuitive and easy to learn API properly using HTTP verbs and good practices.

Comment: you didnt get what i want i use my own API i did for mobile

Comment: Add more detail then, I can't see about two Laravel projects anywhere